# Convert to a list to a data.frame with multiple columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, rbind

I have a list from a .json file that looks like this.

```
[[1]]
[1] list ()
[[2]] 
[1] integer(0)
[[3]]
[1] 0 9
[[4]]
[1] 3
```

I would like to transform this list into a data.frame that looks like this

```
column1 column2
  NA     NA 
  NA     NA
   0     9   
   3     NA
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can try `library(plyr)` and `do.call(rbind.fill,yourlist)`

Comment: If your list is called `l1`, then try ```do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, `length<-`, max(lengths(l1))))``` or `t(stringi::stri_list2matrix(l1))`